# making a map of usa in r with earnings for men and women

Tags: r, google-maps, geom-bar

i want to make a google map with geom_point. I have two colomns for earnings for men and women and I want to show them together on the same map.

```
 state   capital_name     lat        long      women earnings    men earning            

 1   Alabama   Montgomery   32.36154  -86.27912        621              832    

 2    Alaska     Juneau     58.30194  -134.41974       797              1008 

 3    Arizona   Phoenix     33.44846  -112.07384       669              827  

 4    Arkansas Little Rock  34.73601  -92.33112        610              703
```

as you can see, in the same numbers, i now have woman earnings and man earnings. I want them to be shown in the map together.

I tried to pot a plus (+) to the code for pot it together with on resolt. this in my code:

```
          mapPoints <-
          #the woman:
           ggmap(map) + geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat, size = 
          sqrt(women_median_weekly_earnings)), data = join2, alpha = .5 
            ,color="darkred")+scale_size(range=c(3,20))

#the men:
+ ggmap(map) + geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat, size = 
sqrt(men_median_weekly_earnings)), data = join2, alpha = .5 
,color="blue")+scale_size(range=c(3,20))
```

I have an eror problem as follow:

```
         Error in add_ggplot(e1, e2, e2name) : 
         argument "e2" is missing, with no default
```

Each of them works separately but not together.

the women:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw2M2.jpg)

the men: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeub8.jpg)

also, maybe geom_point is not so good? I cant see the us states. there is maybe somethig else even better to shot this data on the map? columns\bars maybe?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

#### Data prep

```
df <- read.table(text = "state   capital_name     lat        long      women_earnings    men_earning            
                                 Alabama   Montgomery   32.36154  -86.27912        621              832    
                                 Alaska     Juneau     58.30194  -134.41974       797              1008 
                                 Arizona   Phoenix     33.44846  -112.07384       669              827  
                                 Arkansas Little_Rock  34.73601  -92.33112        610              703", header = T)


## I'm going to reshape the data into long-form so it's easier to work with 
library(reshape2)

df <- melt(df, id.vars = c("state", "capital_name", "lat", "long"), value.name = "earnings")
```

#### ggmap

```
ggmap(map) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat, size = sqrt(earnings), colour = variable), 
                         data = df, alpha = .5) +
    scale_colour_manual(values  = c("red", "darkblue")) +
    scale_size(range=c(3,20), guide = 'none')
```

[image]

If you want an interactive map there are a few options, in particular `leaflet` and `googleway`. There are differences in how they both 'accept' the data, but it's not too much manipulation.

#### Leaflet

```
library(leaflet)

colourPalette <- colorFactor(c("red", "darkblue"), unique(df$variable))

df %>%
    leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addCircles(radius = ~(earnings * 500), stroke = FALSE, 
                         fillColor = ~colourPalette(variable)) %>%
    addLegend(pal = colourPalette, values = unique(df$variable))
```

[image]

#### Googleway

```
library(googleway)


mapKey <- 'your_api_key'

## the colours and radius are required on the data itself
df_colours <- data.frame(variable = unique(df$variable), 
                                                 colour = c("red", "darkblue"))

df <- merge(df, df_colours, by = "variable")
df$radius <- df$earnings * 500

google_map(key = mapKey) %>%
    add_circles(data = df, fill_colour = "colour", radius = "radius")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the approach of SymbolixAU, but here's some code that makes only minor changes to the approach outlined in your question.

```
library(ggmap)
library(RCurl)
library(dplyr)

# Create dataframe 
join_2  <- 
tibble::tribble(
~state, ~capital_name, ~lat,        ~long, ~women_earning, ~men_earning,
"Alabama",  "Montgomery",   32.36154,   -86.27912,  621,    832,
"Alaska",     "Juneau",     58.30194,   -134.41974, 797,    1008,
"Arizona",  "Phoenix",    33.44846, -112.07384, 669,    827,
"Arkansas", "Little Rock",34.73601, -92.33112,  610,    703)

# Get map 
map <- get_map(location = c(mean(join_2$long),mean(join_2$lat)), zoom = 3)
#> Map from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=39.711987,-106.275955&zoom=3&size=640x640&scale=2&maptype=terrain&language=en-EN&sensor=false

# Produce map 
ggmap(map) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat, size = sqrt(women_earning)), 
             data = join_2, alpha = .5, color="darkred") + 
  geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat, size = sqrt(men_earning)), 
             data = join_2, alpha = .5,color="blue") +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(3,20))
```

[image]